# Request for suggestions to improve very simple PICKLE-based blog code

Tags: python

In experimenting with pickle, I've put together some code for a (very) simple blog.  It's intended to display time-stamped blog contents from a pickle'd list in reverse chron order.  It then prompts whether you want to add to the blog.  (As you can see, I'm new to programming). Please critique this and/or suggest ways to make this even more efficient.  This was written for Python 2.7.  Also, I've saved this as Journal.py.  I call it by issuing "reload(Journal)".  How would I call this module without the "reload" command ?Thank you.

```
import pickle
import time
from time import strftime


archive_log = []
new_log = []

with open('journal.pickle','r') as f:
    archive_log = pickle.load(f)
    for item in reversed(archive_log):
        print item

proceed = 'y'
cont = []
while proceed == 'y':
    cont = raw_input('Add an entry ? ')
    if cont == 'n':
        break
    else:
        new_log = (strftime('%Y%m%d %H:%M:%S *%a* ') + raw_input('Enter new info '))
        archive_log.append(new_log)
        with open('journal.pickle', 'w') as f:
            pickle.dump(archive_log, f)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your immediate question, you can run this code by using:

```
python Journal.py
```

and things should mostly work (I didn't test your code, just glanced at it). To improve upon it, you should look at Guido's guide to using main() [here](http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=4829) and possibly utilizing a #! ([reference](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/interpreter.html#executable-python-scripts)) so you can do:

```
./Journal.py
```